# Stopping a threadpool on satisfied condition

Tags: java, threadpool, concurrent-programming

I'm using the ExecutorService to process thousands of small independent tasks. Each task, on completion, stores the result (which is either true of false).

So, instead of processing all of the tasks, I want to shutdown the threadpool prematurely, if a task has found the answer!
It feels like I'm missing something very obvious here...

Comment: How many cores do you have?  If you have say 4 cores, the optimal number of tasks may be 4. Perhaps you can have a small number of tasks which check all the results and a common flag to determine when to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the `invokeAny` method.  It returns when just one is done.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Actually, when one is done without throwing an exception. Which means that task results shouldn't be true/false but an exception unless the task found the answer.

Comment: I've tried invokeAny, where I've thrown an exception if task's result was false, but that ends the processing prematurely because I've caught that exception (because invokeAny is in a try-catch block). Is my solution to throw an exception on true, instead of false result?

Comment: invokeAny returns when any of the invoked callables return a value.  If you do not want the false results considered in this, throw an exception.

Comment: Ah yes, it works fine. My problem was throwing the RuntimeException on Interrupted & Execution exceptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The desire you express reminds me of a [Klein bottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle), where there's little distinction maintained between what's "inside" and what's "outside." Here, the tasks submitted to the `ExecutorService` need to know that they must notify a *latching gate* outside the thread pool and shut it down when first transitioning from having seen no true task outcomes to having seen at least one.

I won't write the code for you, but I'll sketch the solution. It may help to define an interface on which the tasks must call when they complete:

```
interface TaskObserver
{
  void completed(boolean result);
}
```

Each task instance can be constructed with a reference to such a `TaskObserver`, on which the task body will call just before it completes and yields control back to the invoking `ExecutorService`. You could even write a base class to assist in participating in this protocol:

```
public abstract class ObservableTask implements Callable<Boolean>
{
  protected ObservableTask(TaskObserver observer)
  {
    if (null == observer)
      throw NullPointerException();
    observer_ = observer;
  }


  public final Boolean call()
  {
    final boolean result = evaluate();
    observer_.completed(result);
    return result;
  }


  protected abstract boolean evaluate();


  private final TaskObserver observer_;
}
```

Alternately, instead of using extension to define tasks, you could write a concrete class like this that accepts a *reference* to a `Callable<Boolean>` in its constructor in addition to the `TaskObserver` reference, and works through delegation instead.

Moving on, the implementation of `TaskObserver` will store an [`AtomicBoolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), which must be set to false initially. The body of the `completed(boolean)` method must attempt to set the `AtomicBoolean` from false to true if the result passed to `completed(boolean)` is true. If the transition from false to true is successful, shut down the `ExecutorService` and stop submitting any more tasks; any subsequent calls calls to the `TaskObserver` will come from tasks that had already been submitted and were too far along to comply with a cancellation request.

```
public void complete(boolean result)
{
  if (result &&
      latch_.compareAndSet(false, true))
  {
    // Set a flag to cease submitting new tasks.
    service_.shutdownNow();
    if (!service_.awaitTermination(timeoutMagnitude, timeoutUnit))
    {
      // Report a problem in shutting down the pool in a timely manner.
    }
  }
}
```

If that's not enough of a push to get you started, please follow up with additional questions.